# How to read times between noon and 1 PM using readr

Tags: r, date, readr

> I'm trying to parse some times in a google spreadsheet using the `googlesheets` library, which makes a call to `readr`.

I can parse almost any time of day with no problem. For example, this works as it should:

```
>library('readr')
>parse_datetime("2015 01:14 PM", "%Y %H:%M %p")

"2015-01-01 13:14:00 UTC"
```

However, for times between 12:00 and 12:59 PM, I get a parsing failure warning and an NA result. For example reading something with a time of 12:14 PM results in this:

```
>parse_datetime("2015 12:14 PM", "%Y %H:%M %p")

Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row col   expected        actual
  1  -- valid date 2015 12:14 PM

NA
```

How do I format either the time or the format string in order to read times between 12:00 and 12:59 PM?

Comment: Looks like a bug that was apparently fixed: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/618. Can you update your `readr` version?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize my R version was so out of date.

Comment: Or read it as a string and then use lubridate to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marius got it in a comment above. With `readr` updated to v1.1.1, I get:

```
> parse_datetime("2015 12:14 PM", "%Y %H:%M %p")
"2015-01-01 12:14:00 UTC"
```